# Spring MVC + Joda Time + @DateTimeFormat

Tags: java, spring

**Descrição:**

O *Spring* não converte utilizando o `@DateTimeFormat`, tento mandar o `start` das duas formas abaixo e ele me retorna um `404`. Quando envio o objeto sem esse campo ele cria o objeto normal, mas não consegue criar quando faço a `request` com o campo `start`.

---

**Primeira tentativa**

```
`@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "HH:mm")
 @Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalTimeAsString")
 LocalTime start`
```

---

**Segunda tentativa**

```
`@Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalTimeAsString")
 @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy")
 private DateTime start;`
```

---

**Documentação do Spring:**

```
`Use @DateTimeFormat to format
java.util.Date, java.util.Calendar, java.util.Long, or Joda Time fields.`
```

Comment: O Joda Time está no Classpath? Qual versão?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeira coisa que você precisa verificar é as versões do JodaTime e do Spring.

Na declaração da sua entidade você não precisa declarar a anotação @Type, o spring já fez a implementação da anotação @DateTimeFormat com integração direta ao JodaTime.